# Noob Alarm!! Why is my module not working?

Tags: python, module

Hi i am new in python on so however in coding, so i am still trying to unravel the mystery.
I have made a module from a book and the only thing that happens when i try to run it, it restarts my shell. Where am i going wrong?
my module code is simple:

```
    def print_seconds_per_day():
        hours = 24
        minutes = hours * 60
        seconds = minutes * 60
        print(seconds)
            
    print_seconds_per_day()
```

can please somebody point me out why is this happening? There must be a version difference in the book even though it says its using python3. Have been looking at different examples but i can't find the problem.

Comment: `print_seconds_per_day()` is not defined as a function. You may either change`def seconds_per_day` to `def print_seconds_per_day` or just call `seconds_per_day()`. `print(seconds_per_day())`  is not necessary, as `seconds_per_day()` returns nothing.

Comment: There could be many reasons this fails. If this is the first time you're using python, maybe python is not installed. You should show us the error you're getting. "restarts the shell" sounds very strange, there is no reason such a simple program would do that, even if incorrect. Are you typing a command in an existing shell ? Or using an IDE ?

Comment: May I suggest using a python specific IDE for your development? Something like PyCharm or Eclipse with Pydev. Any decent IDE would've shown you curly lines under your print_seconds_per_day method stating it's not defined anywhere. Paying attention to these kind of details will save you a lot of frustration as well as time.

Comment: Using Pycharm it shows me something different.  It says Process finished with exit code 0. I have to say that i am trying it on my Mac and on my Windows 10 laptop but both of them are giving me the same results.btw i am using the ide from python3

Comment: Just for your info, to show code you need to use backticks (__`__) not apostrophes (__'__). I edited your post, if you edit you will see how it works

Comment: If your code is exactly as shown in this question then the output will be 86400. I suspect that *print_seconds_per_day()* is indented. If that's the case then your program **will** terminate normally but it won't actually do anything

Comment: @vlad That was it!!!! With all your help guys it finally works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the "print_" on your last line so that it reads

```
seconds_per_day()
```

and you'll be fine.

Also, are the three ''' at the beginning and end in your original code as well? Because if yes, you have to remove them. The ''' make a block comment out of your code so you can't execute it.

Comment: I have tried your approaches but nothing is working. i am not getting any error just a restart of my shell. I think it has to do with my python installation. All environment variables are set, so this is also not the problem.  Trying it in Pycharm it gave me an error Process finished with exit code 0. The ''' on the beginning and the end of the block was mandatory from stack overflow to post the block. the block i tried in pycharm was: '''def print_seconds_per_day(),  hours =24 , minutes = hours * 60, seconds=minutes * 60, print(seconds)''' but then without the commas and the '''

Comment: @Alexandra:  In PyCharm, "Process finished with exit code 0" means everything worked well. I use PyCharm as well, and (after removing the "print_" part), the code runs fine. So just to be sure: Just in the lines above  "Process finished with exit code 0", you don't see the number  86400 printed on a single line?

Comment: no just that its finished  with  exit code 0, but no print result